# Bug with and without linked test cases

Tags: azure-devops

1. I want to pin a chart to the Azure DevOps Services dashboard that shows how many bugs in the current sprint have a linked test case or not.

I have been able to put up a query for the same but it appears that such queries can't be charted out. Is there an alternate way?

[image]

Here's the error that I get while creating a chart out of my query

[image]

[image]

2. Additionally, I would also like to know if there is a way to ensure that when I Resolve/Close a bug workitem in AzDo services, I can check if there is at least one associated test case work item with the bug. I have explored Bug rules but can't find out a clean way to get the link types associated with the work item. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: For tip1, you should create a shared query and it should work then.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT: It gives me an error message "Charting is not supported for tree or direct link queries
Change the type of query or create a new flat-list query to start charting."

Comment: Which chart do you use? Try using `Query Results` instead of `Chart for work items`. The first one supports ` tree or direct link queries` while the second one not.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I have updated my post with the chart interface that I am using. Normally, I would run the query and then go to the "Chart" subtab and then pin the widget to the dashboard

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I also attached the error when using `'Chart for work items'`

Comment: The `Chart for work items` is a widget in dashboards, it [now doesn't support](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365598/create-chart-for-a-tree-query-or-a-direct-links-qu.html) `tree or direct link queries`. There might be some time before the feature comes true. Sorry for the inconvenience :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have been able to put up a query for the same but it appears that
>   such queries can't be charted out. Is there an alternate way?

As for the error you got, it's one open issue [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365598/create-chart-for-a-tree-query-or-a-direct-links-qu.html) in our feedback forum, the product team is considering about it. But there might be some time before the feature comes true. You can track the issue to get notifications if there's any update. Sorry for the inconvenience.

> Is there an alternate way?

If you just need a widget to display the results of the query, you can consider using `Query Results` widget, if supports tree or direct links. But if you do want the pie chart for WITs, I afraid it's not supported for now when using tree or direct links. You can check the related extensions [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=chart&target=AzureDevOps&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance).

> I have explored Bug rules but can't find out a clean way to get the
>   link types associated with the work item. How can I achieve this?

As I know we don't have such option in Azure Devops Boards. 
If we close/delete one workItem, it won't display a prompt or what that tells us the related workItems are still active.

But I think that would be a great idea, so I suggest you can post one feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) to share your idea to product team. Then we can share the feature request link here and people who interested in that would vote for you! Hope all above make some help :)

Comment: Ok. Will do. That really helps